# json_encode to google chart not working

Tags: php, json

Based on a mysql query this php code

```
<?php 

    $out = ''; 

            $out .= "[ <br>";

            $out .=  "[\"Month\", \"Samples Processed\", { role: \"style\" } ], <br>" ;

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $out .= "[\"{$row['date_month']}\", {$row['sample_no']}, \"color: #0066FF\" ], <br>";

            }

            $out .= "]";

        ?>

        <?php echo $out; ?>
```

generates:

```
[ 
["Month", "Samples Processed", { role: "style" } ], 
["September 2014", 3, "color: #0066FF" ], 
["January 2015", 119, "color: #0066FF" ], 
["February 2015", 81, "color: #0066FF" ], 
["March 2015", 123, "color: #0066FF" ], 
["April 2015", 49, "color: #0066FF" ], 
]
```

As does this script

```
<script>
  var chartData = <?php echo json_encode($out); ?>;
  document.write (chartData);
</script>
```

And this script generates a chart

```
script type="text/javascript">

    var chartData = <?php echo json_encode($out); ?>;

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(

       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
    ["Month", "Samples Processed", { role: "style" } ], 
    ["September 2014", 3, "color: #0066FF" ], 
    ["January 2015", 119, "color: #0066FF" ], 
    ["February 2015", 81, "color: #0066FF" ], 
    ["March 2015", 123, "color: #0066FF" ], 
    ["April 2015", 49, "color: #0066FF" ], 
    ]);

      );

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 150,
        bar: {groupWidth: "85%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  </script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 800px; height: 200x;"></div>
```

But when I replace the .arrayToDataTable data with

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($out); ?>;);
```

No chart is displayed. Similarly if I create a variable within the main script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var chartData = <?php echo json_encode($out); ?>;
```

and use

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

No chart is rendered.

Where is the syntax/method error?

Comment: ain't `<?php echo $out; ?>` enough? Please consider pasting generated code

Comment: use chartData = '<?php echo json_encode($out); ?>'